# LSTM Regression with Multilabels and Long Time Window

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I have been struggling to develop an LSTM for my data. So please, bear with me if this post has too much extra stuff.

On my data, features are each formed with 12500 lines where each line has 2 columns. For this test, I have 90 of these. (I will expand this 90 to way more). So, I am passing to my LSTM the following shape and type:

- x_train.shape: `(90, 12500, 2)`
- type(x_train): `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

e.g.
`x_train[0]
array([[ 28.15149259, -21.2996635 ],
       [ 45.98779437, -34.60591158],...`

Labels are each formed of 1 line where each line has 4 columns. So, I am passing to my LSTM the following shape:

- y_train.shape: `(90, 4)`
- type(y_train): `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

e.g. `y_train[0]
array([-0.05552651, -0.1108113 ,  0.02395229,  0.04790576])`

I will like to predict these 4 numbers for each new feature (e.g. not the probability or the class).

For my Keras Model, I have the following:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(12500, 2))) # With 32 it will not work but with 4 it will;
model.add(Dense(4))
#model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')

model.fit(x_train, y_train, nb_epoch=1, batch_size=30, verbose=1)
```

Is this approach make sense? The code is working, in other words, the model fits and I can make predictions. My question is more towards how I properly configure my layers.

Side note: In this case, we have 12500 objects because they are a reference to a pulse of an electrical signal. Each one of these 12500 is, for example, a measurement taken during a millisecond.

Comment: any errors you've got?

Comment: @PaulLo, I don't get any erros when fitting. I editted my question. My question is more toward how I am addding the layers to my LSTM and if that would be the right approach.

Comment: Is each feature 12500x2? And you have 90 features?